# Avoiding more than one cronjob in parallel in node.js

Tags: node.js, cron

I would like to do some cronjob using the Node.js package "[cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron)" every 10 minutes.
This cronjob takes between 5 to 15 minutes, and I don't want that in a case that one instance is still running - another will be joining it in parallel. Instead, it will skip the additional running and wait until the next period.
Is it possible to implement it using this package?
Here is the code of the implementation using the cron package :

```
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;
const job = new CronJob(
    '0 */10 * * * *',
    ()=>SomeCronJob(),
    null,
    true,
    'America/Los_Angeles',
);
```

I thought of implementing it using a combination of simple setInterval() and clearInterval() instead of the package, not sure how though.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a flag to check if the job is running. Example:

```js
let isJobRunning = false;

function SomeCronJob() {
    if (isJobRunning) {
        // Skip
        return;
    }

    isJobRunning = true;

    // run stuff

    // Once is finished

    isJobRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: Just be mindful if your code throws an exception, the flag won't be reset. Packing it into a try ... finally block would help